# Is KornShell pattern a regular expression?

Tags: regular-expression, wildcards, ksh

KornShell pattern extends POSIX shell "glob" patterns (i.e. `*`, `?`, etc.) with repetition specifiers such as `*(...)`, `+(...)`, as well as negation among many nice features.

In a hobbist project, I intend to implement these patterns for string processing instead of various variants of regex such as BRE, ERE, JavaScript RegExp. One major benefit I perceive is that it'll be less verbose in C strings, as the backslash characters can be avoided when writing the patterns.

My limited understanding of computer science suggests that the features supported by KornShell patterns qualify it as a specification of a regular grammar.

Question: Is that technically correct? (Even if it's not, I still perceive this sublanguage as valuable and desirable.)

Comment: "as the backslash characters can be avoided when writing the patterns" ... which backslash characters do you think you'll avoid in comparison to ERE or JavaScript's RE?

Comment: @muru My idiocracy. I suppose since the glob patterns are designed for filenames, the KornShell patterns will better adapt to this application than regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, that can qualify as regular expression, so do the extendedglob glob patterns of zsh which have a more direct translation from regular extended regexp:

| ERE | zsh | ksh93 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `.` | `?` | `?` |
| `x*` | `x#` | `*(x)` |
| `x+` | `x##` | `+(x)` |
| `x{1,2}` | `x(#c1,2)` | `{1,2}(x)` |
| `[...]` | `[...]` | `[...]` |
| `(...)` | `(...)` | `@(...)` |
| `a|b` | `(a|b)` | `@(a|b)` |
| `^` | `(#s)` | none¹ |
| `$` | `(#e)` | none¹ |
| `x?` | `(|x)` | `?(x)` |
| `\1`² | none² | `\1` |

The `printf` builtin of ksh93 can even translate regexps from one dialect to another:

```
$ printf '%P\n' '^(x{1,3})?a+'
?({1,3}(x))+(a)*
$ printf '%R\n' '*(x)'
^(x)*$
```

The ast-open implementation of `grep` has a `-K` / `--ksh-regexp` to match using ksh93 extended glob patterns.

But I would still avoid calling it *regexp* as that would likely only lead to confusion.

---

<sup>¹ though glob patterns are often anchored by default or in some context can be anchored via some external syntax like the `${var/#pattern/replacement}` which is like `${var/pattern/replacement}` with the pattern anchored at the start.</sup>

<sup>² there's no back-reference in standard ERE, only in standard BRE, though some ERE engines support it as an extension. In any case, both zsh and ksh93 support *capturing* parts of a match and recall it later (`$MATCH`/`$match[1]` enabled with `(#m)`/`(#b)` in zsh or `\0`/`${.sh.match[0]}` (full match like `sed`'s `&`) `\1`/`${.sh.match[1]}` in ksh93 depending on context.</sup>

Comment: Back-reference in ERE is un-escaped parentheses according to XPG-7 / Single Unix Specification version 4. (un-escaped in the sense that it's not preceeded by back-slash).

Comment: @DannyNiu, that's just grouping. `(.)\1` to match two identical characters is not in POSIX ERE. There's `\(.\)\1` in POSIX BRE though. (and POSIX BREs don't have `|` while some implementations support `\|` as an extension just like some ERE implementations support `\1` as an extension; in POSIX `awk` EREs `\1` the character of value  1 like `\001`)